# How to determine points along a GDI+ path

Tags: .net, gdi+, system.graphics

Does GDI+ ([System.Drawing.Graphics in .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx)) offer some method to determine points on a [graphics path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.aspx)?

Specifically, I'm hoping to find an easy way to write the following function:

```
 Point positionAt(GraphicsPath path, Single where)
```

with `where` a number between 0 and 1 specifying how far to travel along the path.

Answer (score 2):

Try the GraphicsPath.GetPathData method:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535534(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this method and it looks useful.  I would still have to write my logic to get the answer, which is no fun for Bezier curves.

Comment: In that case, write your own Bezier curves! It's not hard *at all*. And you'll get your [0, 1] range right there as a concequence of the implementation.